# SQL query for grouping all teams with the same category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an app in which User can create championship tables with teams and points. 
I have championships table. There will be saved all teams, points, games, goalDifference, etc.

So here are my models:

```
class Championship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  validates :team, presence: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :championships

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

With model category user creates age categories (beginners, juniors, seniors).

Tables from schema.rb

```
 create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "championships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "team"
    t.integer  "games_played",    default: 0
    t.integer  "wins",            default: 0
    t.integer  "draws",           default: 0
    t.integer  "lost",            default: 0
    t.string   "goal_difference", default: "0 - 0"
    t.integer  "points",          default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end
```

View:

```
<tbody>
        <% @championships.each do |championship| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= championship.team %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :games_played, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :wins, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :draws, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :lost, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :goal_difference, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :points, as: :input %></td>
            <td><%= link_to edit_admin_championship_path(championship) do %>
              <i class="material-icons edit-event">mode edit</i>
            <% end %>
            </td>
            <td><%= link_to admin_championship_path(championship), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Jeste li sigurni?" }, class: "delete" do %>
              <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            <% end %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

I want to select all teams with the same category and place them in one championship table in view. I want to select all teams by categories so that all juniors are in one table, beginners in second table and seniors in third table.

**Question: How should I write SQL query for selecting all teams with the same category?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_by http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by . It will look something like this

```
Championship.all.group_by{|champ| champ.category.name}.each do |category, champs| 
      puts category.to_s
      champs.each do |champ|
        puts champ.team
      end
    end
```

In a view

```
<% Championship.all.group_by{|champ| champ.category.name}.each do |category, champs|  %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category %></td>
      </tr>
    <% champs.each do |championship| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= championship.team %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :games_played, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :wins, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :draws, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :lost, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :goal_difference, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place [:admin, championship], :points, as: :input %></td>
        <td><%= link_to edit_admin_championship_path(championship) do %>
          <i class="material-icons edit-event">mode edit</i>
        <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to admin_championship_path(championship), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Jeste li sigurni?" }, class: "delete" do %>
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        <% end %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what´s the error or problem? Probably you need to change it a little to adjust to your models, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Error is `undefined method name for #<Championship...`

Comment: What is team? a string ? the name of the team? then you should use puts champ.team.to_s (remove the name)

Comment: Team is a string, but error is in first line `category.name`

Comment: Still the same error.. I have updated question with schema tables

Comment: What´s exactly the error? in the comment is cut. Maybe there are championships without related category? Try champ.category_id instead of champ.category.name

Comment: That part I think now works. Next error is in view where I want to display teams. It says `undefined method team `

Comment: you can use a similar code in a view, check the updated example

Comment: it works, thanks.. only for some reason it displays me whole sql output code before table?

Comment: mmm be carefull with <%  and <% = , if you have the = it will print whatever inside. But in my code it´s using <% so not sure why is happening.

Comment: Yes, I know..I will fix it somehow.. I will accept your answer.. And only one tip if you can help me.. how should I display `category.name` instead of `<%= category %>`

Comment: When you do group_by{|champ| champ.category.name}, it will return a hash with champ.category.name => championships.  than then you use in do |category, champs| so in that case category should be the category name. If you are using champ.category_id then it will be the id.